# Embedding video

Tags: sharepoint-online, video

I've got a requirement to embed video on out intranet site.  I've tried following the instructions here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/blogs/office_365_technical_blog/archive/2011/09/26/hosting-and-embedding-video-with-sharepoint-online.aspx

My insert tab on the ribbon doesn't have a gadgets are.  How do I enable this?  Is it a 3rd party add-on I'm missing or something I need to enable in config?

This blog gives another way of doing it:  http://www.bfcnetworks.com/embed-youtube-and-other-code-into-sharepoint-2010/  but that seems like an incredibly convoluted way of putting an iframe on a web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link gives simple instructions in how to embed video in a SharePoint page:

http://msfarmer.blogspot.in/2009/05/embedding-video-on-your-sharepoint-site_13.html

So the major heavy lifting will be done by the `<embed>` tag:

```
   <embed src="http://link to video here"
      autoplay="true"
      loop="false"
      width="200"
      height="200">
   </embed>
```

Comment: That works fine on out internally hosted 2007 site but on the 2010 online version you only get the rich text editor, not the HTML editor.

Comment: When you add the Content Editor Web Part to the page:
1) Go to Edit WebPart
2) Go to 'Editing Tools' tab
3) Go to 'Format Text' sub tab. 
4) In the Markup ribbon Group, you will find the HTML ribbon button.
You can edit the html of the Content Editor WebPart from there.

Comment: If I use embed or iframe tags in there I get:  "Warning: The HTML source you entered might have been modified." and it renders blank.

Comment: Save it and then refresh the page.

Comment: After several save+refreshes it eventually worked!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to embedding YouTube video using [ContentEditorWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.aspx) web part, I recommend to take a look on different approaches as described below.

---

### Store embedded video properties in Custom List

The main idea is to store embedded video properties and not the embedded code itself. For storage Custom List named **Video Links** is used. Custom List is based on OOTB Links List.
Resulting page for Video Links list (default view with embedded player) looks like shown below

Default List View
[image]

[More details](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint/)

### Store embed code in Custom List

This approach  allows to save embed code in Custom List as it was generated.
For displaying video player Computed Field is used.

Additional features:

- Support for different video providers listed in [oEmbed specification](http://www.oembed.com/)
- Thumbnail view for displaying video arranged by columns. 
  [image]
- Alternative mode for posting the embed code for video into SharePoint. It is possible now **to copy the embed code as it was generated by Provider and  paste it into SharePoint**
  [image]
  [image]

[More details](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint-part-two-posting-embedded-code-support-for-different-video-providers-preview-view/)

### Aggregate video from RSS/Atom feeds

This solution allows to display videos from YouTube Feed. For rendering video content  [RSSAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.rssaggregatorwebpart%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web part is used.

[image]

[More details](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint-part-three-aggregating-video-feeds-and-utilizing-api/)