# Embed MP4 and make not downoadable

Tags: 2010, 2007, video, html5

I have the task to embed a mp4 video on our Sharepoint 2010 or 2007 Site. The video should play in IE9+ and Chrome.

Also the video should not be downloadable by anyone. I know that there is no solution to make a video not downloadable, but it should be as hard as possible to do it. I have read about a solution to draw a HTML5 canvas, load the video in background and draw every frame to the canvas. So if someone trys to download the video, he will only get an image from the current frame.

I tried to implement the Video in SP2007 Web Part with this approach:

```
<embed src="http://link to video here"
      autoplay="true"
      loop="false"
      width="200"
      height="200">
</embed>
```

It is working on IE but when i navigate on that page with chrome, it is downloading the video automatically instead of playing it.

Also right click disabling is not working with this code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
   });
<script>
```

Can anyone help me with this task or give me some hints for a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can make it harder for users to download disabling the right-click-save-as function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
```

Reference: One answer to the question [Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736367/286244)

Comment: But in which way should i embed the video into the website from the code view? Because in many cases, the browser is asking the user if he wants to view or download the video when the video should autoplay.

Comment: @Floeee Like this [Embedding video](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/40914/6382)

Comment: edited my post with approaches i tried and the results